# Why does netbean behave this way?

Tags: php, netbeans

[image]

According to my netbeans, the value of $res is null.

That can't be. When it's decoded as json it shows something well.

The value of $res is not null. In fact, I echo it and it shows the json.

But on netbeans watch, it's null. As you can clearly see in the screenshot.

Anyone have had this problem? It's the first time I see this sort of things.

Comment: With netbeans format your code by hitting `ALT+SHIFT+F`

Comment: what does it mean?